# Storing data in Arrays (Java)

Tags: java

I'm just a beginner in Java. Can someone please tell me how to arrange this program. In this program I want to store 10 marks in an array, and then output the ones that are equal to or greater than the average. Help would be appreciated.

```
public class ClassAverage{
public static void main (String Args []){

    int sum = 0;
    int mark[] = new int [10];

    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){

        System.out.print("Enter a mark: ");
        mark[c] = Keyboard.readInt();

        }
    sum = sum + mark[c];
    int average = sum / 10;

    if(mark[c]>=average){
    System.out.print(mark[c]);

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thihara, im still in secondary school :P

Comment: @user2291293 so,you won't pay attention in class ??

Comment: im studying for my exams and i got stuck what's so strange about that?

Comment: @user2291293 hell if I knew your age I wouldn't have posted my original comment... If you are telling the truth consider me impressed.. And accept my apologies.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The question seemed to be poorly constructed with no error details or anything... Hence my comment to which I have apologized... :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need loop the array twice. The first iteration sums all the elements and computes the average. And the other iteration outputs the elements that meet your constraints.

The code is below:

```
public class ClassAverage{
    public static void main (String Args []){

        int sum = 0;
        int mark[] = new int [10];
        // The first iteration sums all elements
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
            System.out.print("Enter a mark: ");
            mark[c] = Keyboard.readInt();

            sum = sum + mark[c];
        }
        int average = sum / 10;
        // This iteration outputs elements that meet your requirements.
        for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
            if(mark[c]>=average){
                System.out.print(mark[c]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just some modification in your code.

```
public class ClassAverage{
public static void main (String Args []){

    int sum = 0;
    int mark[] = new int [10];

    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){

        System.out.print("Enter a mark: ");
        mark[c] = Keyboard.readInt();

        sum = sum + mark[c];
    }
    int average = sum / 10;

    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){

        if(mark[c]>=average)
            System.out.print(mark[c]);

    }    
}
```

**Explanation**

1. You need to add each element to sum to get the total. So add each element within the for loop after taking input
2. you also need to check each element to compare with the average. So you need to iterate the array again to compare each element.

Comment: May be I shouldn't :s, feeling guilty now after doing someone's homework. You can free my guilt by learning how it really works

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another `for` loop to iterate your array after calculating the average. Here is the updated code with the required `for` loop:

```
public static void main (String Args []){
    int sum = 0;
    int mark[] = new int [10];

    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {    
        System.out.print("Enter a mark: ");
        mark[c] = Keyboard.readInt();
        sum = sum + mark[c];
    }

    int average = sum / 10;
    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
        if(mark[c]>=average){
            System.out.print(mark[c]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class aver{
  public static void main (String Args []){

    int sum = 0;
    int mark[] = new int [10];
    int average;
    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
        System.out.print("Enter a mark: ");
        mark[c] = Keyboard.readInt();
    }
    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
        sum = sum + mark[c];
    }
    average = sum / 10;
    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
        if(mark[c]>=average){
           System.out.println(mark[c]);
        }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = sum + mark[c];
```

statement must be inside your loop.

```
public class ClassAverage{
public static void main (String Args []){

    int sum = 0;
    int mark[] = new int [10];

    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a mark: ");
        mark[c] = Keyboard.readInt();
         sum = sum + mark[c];
     }
    int average = sum / 10;
    for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
    {
           if(mark[c]>=average)
           {
             System.out.print(mark[c]);

           }
     }
}
```